# Chart.js not loading on reload

Tags: javascript, meteor, charts, chart.js

I'm having a pretty strange issue with Chart.js in Meteor.

I have one chart on the page that gets its data using `Session.get('values');` to get their information. This works fine if you change routes using the menu. However if you push the reload button on the page the chart loads in but the data doesn't, if I hover over the data points on the chart it just shows the label without any number or anything.

If I run the `Session.get('values');` in the console it returns the data fine, and as soon as I click a menu item and then click back on the one with the chart in it, it loads fine!

I am using `Template.templatename.onRendered();` to load in the chart data otherwise the chart doesn't load at all.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When you say the reload button, you mean the browsers refresh button?

Comment: Where are you setting the `Session` value?

Comment: Also, what does the code look like for rendering the chart? The code for rendering a chart for the first time may be different if it requires rerendering. I store the state of the chart to indicate whether it has loaded or not; if it has been loaded, then I use different code to update the data in the chart.

Comment: @Sparticus Yes I mean the refresh button and @Nate I am setting the session values inside the onRendered function. They are above the chartdata array which gets initialised when the chart code is run at the very bottom of the onRendered function. That looks like: `var ctx = document.getElementById("timeChart").getContext("2d");
  window.timeChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true
  });`

Comment: I don't know why the chart doesn't work on reload, but I would suggest making sure that when your chart is re-rendered that you use the correct functions to do so, i.e. remove the data first and add it again, or update the existing:

.update( )

Calling update() on your Chart instance will re-render the chart with any updated values, allowing you to edit the value of multiple existing points, then render those in one animated render loop.

    `timeChart.datasets = lineChartData;
    timeChart.update();`

Comment: I've got the same thing happening, it its the same page it doesn't load if I go to the URL however, if I hit the actual update button on the browser it WILL load but going to the same url with a different attribute in the url will break the graph

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution to this.

Just declare a new variable, say for example `chartUpdated`.
Then in your `created` or `mounted` hook, after you have updated the dynamic values to the chart object, update `this.chartUpdated` to true.

```
data() {
    return {
      chartUpdated: false,
      areaChartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: '',
            data: [],
            borderColor: colors.themeColor1,
            pointBackgroundColor: colors.foregroundColor,
            pointBorderColor: colors.themeColor1,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: colors.themeColor1,
            pointHoverBorderColor: colors.foregroundColor,
            pointRadius: 4,
            pointBorderWidth: 2,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            fill: true,
            borderWidth: 2,
            backgroundColor: colors.themeColor1_10
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const response = await axios.get('https://yourapi.com')
    const data = response.data.data
    this.areaChartData.labels = data.map((x) => x.day)
    this.areaChartData.datasets[0].data = data.map((x) => x.total_member)
    this.chartUpdated = true
  }
```

Then in your template

```
<area-chart v-if="chartUpdated" :data="areaChartData" container-class="chart" shadow />
```